# Sentinel2 Level2A Tile Coordinates are wrong, only simple box, doesn't represent no-data shape

Tags: geojson, tiles, sentinel-2, nodata

For some Sentinel2 L2A tiles, the geometry/coordinate meta data is a simple box and doesn't describe the actual bounds of the tile, for example tile `S2A_MSIL2A_20160313T102022_R065_T32TLR_20210528T144150` has coordinates:

```
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          6.41593488,
          46.0243534
        ],
        [
          6.46078579,
          45.03702312
        ],
        [
          7.85436546,
          45.0595136
        ],
        [
          7.83410809,
          46.04762762
        ],
        [
          6.41593488,
          46.0243534
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

whereas most other tiles (before and after this date), have 10-40 different points in their geometry/coordinate description. Why do some tiles only have a box? These coordinates don't accurately represent the no-data border, as is usually the case.